# downgrading tensorflow to v=2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use keras-tcn:
https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-tcn

But it seems that there is some conflict.
Installing it is downgrading keras from 2.4.3 to 2.3.1. But keras 2.3.1 seems to need tensorflow 2.1.0.

Yet by trying to install tensorflow:
pip install tensorflow == 2.1.0, I do have this error message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.1.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1.0

Does anyone have some solutions for installing it ?

Here are some infos that might be useful

pip : 20.2.4

python : 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your python to 3.7 and install tensorflow 2.1

Comment: Please arrow up this as the accepted answer.